# Content provider pagination

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

What is the correct way to load data from content provider by buckets?
Should I use `LIMIT + OFFSET`? or selection range by ID (`ID > ?`)?
But how to know if the `LIMIT + OFFSET` is not out of range or how to handle when the id jumps (for example sms Id's are mixed per conversation)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the correct way is to work with date and not id's, id's can be mixed up when importing sms messages.

```
val selection = "${Sms.THREAD_ID} = ? ${Sms.DATE}"
val selectionArgs = arrayOf(threadId)
val sortOrder = "${Sms.DATE} DESC LIMIT 100"
```